# Получение атрибутов из модели при запросах к базе

Tags: laravel5, eloquent

Для проекта сделал таблицу для файлов с полями
id, storage, path..
В модели файла создал метод

```
public function getFilePathAttribute() {
    return \Storage::disk($this->storage)->url($this->path);
}
```

в модели пользователя есть например поле avatar - содержащее id из таблицы с файлами
Я хочу вывести пользователей с пагинацией

```
$users = User::all()->with('avatar')->paginate('10');
```

Но как при этом получить filePath в этом случае непонятно. т.к. данные далее передаются в Vue компонент.

Перебирать $users - непонятно как. т.к. там объект пагинатора. Да и поидее бесполезное занятие.
Может есть способы получения вот таких атрибутов вместе с запросом? В принципе мне всегда нужен будет filePath.

Comment: Написал и тут же пришел в голову правильный запрос в гугл   решил так - в Files добавил protected $appends = ['filePath'];

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно было воспользоваться функцией map(). Приведу пример ниже:

```
$paginated = $query->paginate($per_page, ['*'], url()->current(), $page)->appends($appends);
$transformed = $paginated->getCollection()
        ->map(function ($item) {
            return [
                'field' => $item->field
            ];
        });
$result= new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
        $transformed,
        $paginated->total(),
        $paginated->perPage(),
        $paginated->currentPage(), [
            'path' => \Request::url(),
            'query' => [
                'page' => $paginated->currentPage()
            ]
        ]
    );
```